# Place of a time expression in a negative sentence

Tags: grammar, expressions, present-tense, time, present-simple

Is it possible to put the time expressions before or after the negative word?
Or is there only one way?
For example :

The students usually don't like eating fish

The students don't usually like eating fish

Comment: The textbook answer is usually to place the adverb right next to the verb you're modifying. Informally, it can go other places.

Comment: You need "to" in "The students usually don't like **to** eat fish." The position of "usually" can vary, e.g. if you're contrasting it with something else. There are a lot of existing questions about the placement and use of "usually", if you search.

Comment: @StuartF like can take to or not.

Answer (score 0):

As edited, *both* "usually don't like" and "don't usually like" are often heard in colloquial English. Google's [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=usually%20don%27t%20like%2Cdon%27t%20usually%20like&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows them to be of similar frequency in it corpus.

That said, they *might* have slightly different connotations:

"I usually don't like eating fish." This might be seen as a general observation.

"I don't usually like eating fish." Though it could be general, it might be a preface to a further statement, showing an exception, e.g., "Today, however, the cod was delicious."

Answer (score -1):

I usually don't like playing cards.
Adverbs of frequency precede the verb.

I never, sometimes, frequently don't like playing cards.

HOWEVER, **usually** and **ever** can go after the auxiliary:

Some can go after the negative:

- I **don't usually** like playing cards.
- I usually don't like playing cards.
- I **don't ever** like playing cards ever. [never becomes ever in negative sentences.]
- I sometimes like playing cards. [sometimes, usually NO, except as a response.
- Do you sometimes like playing cards?
  OR
- Do you like playing cards sometimes?
- Yes, I like playing cards sometimes.
  OR
- Yes, I sometimes like playing cards.
- No, I do not like sometimes playing cards. [as per context only]

[Please note: this is not everything that can be said about adverbs of frequency\